# How to loop through buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, button, getelementbyid

I have number of different buttons on my website and I want to assign different task to each button, currently I am referencing them one by one using `getElementByID` and because I have so many buttons I ended up writing endless lines of codes just to reference the buttons, having some knowledge of java I understand that what I have done could be achieved with less code using for loop but I am not quite sure how  to go about doing that, any help is welcomed.

Currently this is how I am referencing my buttons:

```
    var Button1Menu = document.getElementById("button1menu"); 
    var Button2Menu = document.getElementById("button2menu"); 
    var Button3Menu = document.getElementById("button3menu"); 
    var Button4Menu = document.getElementById("button4menu"); 
    var Button5Menu = document.getElementById("button5menu"); 
    var Button6Menu = document.getElementById("button6menu"); 
    var Button7Menu = document.getElementById("button7menu"); 
    var Button8Menu = document.getElementById("button8menu"); 
    var Button9Menu = document.getElementById("button9menu"); 
    .....
    .....
    .....
    var Button43Menu = document.getElementById("button43menu");
```

and then I am assigning click listener to each one:

```
Button1Menu.onclick = function() {

     //doing something

  };
```

Is there a better way of achieving this please.

Comment: use event delegation

Comment: How is "Doing something" differing depending on the clicked button?

Comment: Hi @Teemu what do you mean?

Comment: Hi @RajaSekar please can you show me an example.

Comment: What is the difference between the click handlers of the buttons? Are they totally diffrerent, or are they mostly doing the same task, just having some slightly varying part?

Comment: Mostly its the same task but different action within the same task for example, most of the buttons will change text of textfield to something like I am button1 if button is clicked, if button 2 is clicked it will say something like button 2 was clicked.

Comment: I'd definitely go with event delegation, as Raja has suggested. Find a closest common ancestor of the buttons (or create it). Add only a single click handler to the ancestor. Use `addEventListener`, and retrieve the clicked button from the argument. Return, if a button wasn't clicked. Then use DOM tree relations between the clicked button and the target text element to find an element, where the content should be changed. For more varying tasks, add the handler functions into an object, and check, if a function named with the `id` of the clicked button exists, if it exists, call the function.

Answer (score 4):

initiate a counter and keep checking till you get a button that doesn't exist

```
var counter = 1;
var button  = document.getElementById( "button" + counter + "menu" );

while ( button )
{
   button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      //do something here
   });

   button  = document.getElementById( "button" + ( ++counter ) + "menu" );
}
```

if all the buttons needs to be assigned a click event then

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll( "button[id^='button'][id$='menu']" );
for ( var counter = 0; counter < buttons.length; counter++)
{
    buttons[counter].addEventListener("click", function(){
      //do something here
   });
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: _What about `querySelectorAll` ?_

Comment: @RayonDabre OP has not mentioned that he wants to assign click event to all the buttons on his page, just to the ones which are id'd like this. Anyways, will add that solution as well.

Comment: @Teemu oh, thanks for pointing out. changed `counter++` to `++counter`.

Comment: Not my down vote, but the first snippet attaches two handlers to the first button. Also, the question is not clear, all the handlers aren't necessarily the same (they might be though).

Comment: @Teemu actually now he has mentioned in his comment that buttons may do different things. Which actually tells me that OP is not clear on what he/she is looking for. Why would be making 43 buttons on a page and doing different stuff for each of them? Only possible reason for having so many buttons could be for a grid to have a button for each line item.

Comment: I downvoted because your original answer breaks very easy, your edit however is good :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Now inside the click event use the `$(this)` jquery object

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this (**added function `doSomething(item)` to explain a real usage**):

```
    function doSomething(item) {
        switch (item.id) {
            case 'button3menu': 
                // Make this button do something, only it. For example: 
                alert('Hey, you are pressing me!');
                break;
            default:
                // Make all the button's whose id is not contemplated as a case value 
                alert('My id is: ' + item.id);
                break;
    }}

        <script>
        (function()
        {
            var num = 4;
            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                var elem = document.createElement('button');
                elem.id = "button" + i + "menu";
                elem.innerHTML = "button" + i;
                document.body.appendChild(elem)

                elem.addEventListener('click', function(){doSomething(this)});
            }
        })()
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a parent element for all or some of your buttons:

```
<div id="parent">
<button id="button1menu">button</button>
<button id="button2menu">button</button>
<button id="button3menu">button</button>
<button id="button4menu">button</button>
<button id="button5menu">button</button>
<button id="button6menu">button</button>
</div>
```

A single click event listener is enough to handle all of them:

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     // e.target is the clicked element
    //check if button1menu has been clicked
    if(e.target && e.target.id == "button1menu") {
        alert(e.target.id + " was clicked");
    }

    //check if button2menu has been clicked
    if(e.target && e.target.id == "button2menu") {
        alert(e.target.id + " was clicked");
    }

  //etc
 });
```

[You can experiment more in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3p3jtsr6/)

This is called event delegation and its good for you

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution

```js
$("button[id^='button']").on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1menu">button</button>
<button id="button2menu">button</button>
<button id="button3menu">button</button>
<button id="button4menu">button</button>
<button id="button5menu">button</button>
<button id="button6menu">button</button>
```

Comment: Nick, OP hasn't used jquery tag in his OP.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looking for solution - create collection using document.querySelectorAll, and then via loop assign index for every button. After that you can put in each case functionality that you need. It works for simple tasks.

For example below, i have three buttons, by clicking any of them background color will change:

HTML:

```
<div id="page-container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-red">red</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-green">green</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">blue</button>
  <script src="buttonCollection.js"></script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let pageContainer = document.getElementById('page-container')
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
let index = undefined;

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    index = i;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
          pageContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
          break;
      
        case 1:
          pageContainer.style.backgroundColor = "green";
          break;
      
        case 2:
          pageContainer.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
          break;
      
        default:
          pageContainer.style.backgroundColor = "bisque";
          break;
      }
    })
}
```